# Share photo on Facebook for android

Tags: android, facebook

My application's objective is to take a photo using camera activity and save this photo in android internal storage and then allow the user to share this photo in Facebook as wall post, my problem is I couldn't find any source that show/explain how to share photo in FB and I am totally new with Facebook API

Any help PLZ!

Comment: You can share using a Intent, is not necessary uses facebook-sdk. See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827407/how-to-customize-share-intent-in-android/9229654#9229654

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find tutorials ans additional info:
[facebook developers tutorials](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)

**HelloFacebookSample** will fit well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of photo sharing https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/simple

Comment: I tried this example but it is posting the image in somewhere, but not at my wall and give to me the link?! I think that may be I missed something or what?!

Comment: It is my fault, it put them in a photo album and waiting for me to approved it, but what about publishing them to the wall directly?!

Comment: @alex sorry I don't have any experience doing that. I just happened to notice that that example pots pictures when I was learning how do do a sign in with facebook button.