# Sharing a tweet in Android

Tags: android, twitter

I'm developing an Android Application and I want to publish a tweet in twitter. My problem is that I don't know how I do to create a tweet in an android app. I searched for information and I find two possible libraries that may be good for tweet content, the libraries are JTwitter and Twitter4J. When I search the information too people say that OAuth it's difficult, and I don't understand nothing of the OAuth.
If it's possible I want to share an image with the tweet, the image can be a Bitmao object?
And, how I do to insert in the predeterminated tweet this image?

Thanks for the time spended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way that i found to solve this problem is using a sharing intent. In the next link you will have another question with this solution, the only problem is that only work with the official client of twitter.

[How to force Share Intent to open a specific app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app/)

So, with that code you will be able to publish the tweet you want using the twitter client.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally used Twitter4J with great success. However, there is an easier way to share that will open your app up to many more social networks.

You can use a share `Intent`. [This blog](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/) has a great tutorial that walks you through every step. To include an image, you would use `sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)`, where `uri` is the path of the image on the device (content URI or a direct file path).

Comment: Thank you Jason for the fast answer, but I don't undersatnd how you can tweet with your application.

Comment: In my actual app only I want to share on twitter. It's a goo blog and I have another aplication that maybe I include the method in them, but inthe actual only I want tu publish in twitter

Comment: So which part of the implementation of TWitter4J are you stuck on then?