# Tweet in android app instead authenticating the user

Tags: android, twitter

I'm developing an android application and I want to can share in a tweet a picture. I search for tutorials and all of them have to authentificate the user before can post a tweet. Is there any way to use the account that's stored on your phone instead of authenticating the user again?

I don't want to have a share button, I want that like in iPhone can post a tweet.

If anyone know of other toturial that works and it's better please tell me, I don't want a share button, only I want to tweet.

Thanks

Comment: "I don't want to have a share button" -- well-written apps allow their *users* to decide how each *user* wants to share the *user's* content, which may or may not involve Twitter.

Comment: Yes, but the app that I'm develpoing is not like a game that want to share the result, is more like a twitter client.

Comment: If it is a Twitter client, then the user will need to provide you (or Twitter directly via OAuth) with account credentials, because presumably they are not using any other Twitter client.

Comment: I salved finally with a selected share intent. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app
thanks for all

Comment: Use shareIntent 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use shareIntent, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app/8312422#8312422):

```
public void shareTwitter() {
        String message = "Your message to post";
        try {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setClassName("com.twitter.android","com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            startActivity(sharingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("In Exception", "Comes here");
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, theObject.getName());
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("https://mobile.twitter.com/"));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ohh, thanks you, but I found this solution a days ago, sorry for not delete the post...

Comment: can i attach a picture for Tweet ?