# send data to specified app android

Tags: android, android-intent

I read about using ACTION_SEND to get registered list apps from this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

I'm using code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

, but I want send to specified app without the list. How to do that?

Comment: This should solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app

Comment: "I want send to specified app without the list" -- what *you* want is not important. What the *user* wants is important. Please allow the *user* to choose where the *user* shares the *user's* data.

Answer (score -1):

Specify in the intent something that only the specified activity will handle, for instance, a custom mimetype or the actual target class name using [intent.setClassName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClass%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29).