# Android sharing options

Tags: android, android-intent, sharing, android-sharing

I'm writing an app with sharing functionality and I want to have a button to share via a specific social media ie. Facebook, without having to open a chooser. Is there anyway to do this? I've been having a look through the source code to see if I can find anything but so far I can't find a way to do this.

Ideally what I would like to do is call the method that the chooser does to get the list of applicable apps to share with and then display a button for the main social media platforms I am targeting. And then when a user clicks one of the buttons it brings them straight to the app with the media loaded so all they have to do is click post to share.

I know using a chooser isn't rocket science but I want the app to be as simple as possible so removing the chooser would be a good step towards it as it would remove a lot of the unnecessary options like email and some of the things that come with the phone that people don't tend use. Although it is likely that I will have the chooser anyway just incase the user wants to share it some other way too, I would like it not to be the only way to share.

A full solution would be awesome but a point in the right direction in terms of where to look in the source code would be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this but have you tried something like this:

```
Intent fb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
fb.sharingIntent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity");
fb.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");

Intent twitter = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
twitter.setClassName("com.twitter.android","com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
twitter.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(fb, "Share");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {
    twitter, ....more here
});
startActivity(intent);
```

Base on this answer:
[How to force Share Intent to open a specific app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app)

Since these activities can change try the url as well or whatever is documented in their website so it fallbacks to their android intents if installed.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the right way of going about it, At present I am only showing the buttons to share if the relevant app is installed so the fall back shouldn't be needed. I will accept answer when I have it working to make sure it is is the right way of going about it, incase others are looking for it in the future.

Comment: This was the right way to do it, had to read through some of the stuff linked to get it fully working and had to make a function to read the activity from the information gotten from the code below. using the code below rather than declaring them statically 

`Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.setType("image/*");
  List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);`