# How to share bitmap to twitter via my android app?

Tags: android, twitter

I want to share the bitmap that I stored locally in my phone to twitter via my android application. Is it possible? 
Thank You!

Comment: It is possible, Thank You!

Comment: -2 votes? Thanks, And no one knows everything. I am a beginner.
Can anyone give me a tip in doing that!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can give this code a try

```
try {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri phototUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Pictures/yourimage.png");
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, phototUri);
    shareIntent.setClassName("com.twitter.android","com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("https://mobile.twitter.com/compose/tweet"));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this already. But I want to share only on Twitter. This will pop up all the share options!

Comment: check my edit. Try adding the className

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app

Comment: Thanks! It also gives options like Picassa, Gmail , bluetooth, Whatsapp etc. I done facebook share with facebook sdk. I don't want to go out of my app!