# Android Widget - Click imageView to open app

Tags: android, widget, clickable

I have a widget that opens a web address when you click on an imageView resource. I'm having real trouble adapting the code. I would like a specified application to open instead of a web address.

```
package com.example.widget;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider{

   @Override
   public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
   int[] appWidgetIds) {
      for(int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++){
      int currentWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
      String url = "http://www.website.com";
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
      PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
      intent, 0);
      RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
      R.layout.activity_main);
      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView2, pending);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId,views);
      Toast.makeText(context, "widget added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
      }
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);` use package name of specific application you want.
like this sample [How to force Share Intent to open a specific app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app)