# Action send facebook only

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

How can I do `Action.SEND`  with `Intent` to show only facebook app(or to open it at once)?

I did it for all app witg `Action.SEND`:

```
   Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test text");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force Share Intent to open a specific app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app)

Comment: use setpackage parameter in intent