# Whitelist Applications to share files to

Tags: android, file-sharing

I want to be able to share files from my app to applications like Dropbox, GoogleDrive, etc., but not to social media Apps like WhatsApp or Facebook.

Is it possible to create a Whitelist of apps that my files can be shared to, or does Android allow all Apps that are able to receive the filetype to be shared to?

Comment: "Social media" is a marketing term. What, in computer programming terms, are "social media Apps"? Also, what do you mean by "share files"? Do you mean `ACTION_SEND`?

Comment: You can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app

Comment: I think I found the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9151983/2639357 Looks like it's possible to manually filter all possible intents for a "whitelist" and only show the results in the chooser.

Comment: Do you guys happen to know if something similar is possible in iOS?