# Sharing to twitter via intents

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to be able to share text (and later images as well) via an intent but only to the twitter application. I've tried using `setClassName`however this just causes the application to stop. So far I have:

```
String message = "My Text.";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent();
sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

some of the answers I've found but aren't helping are:

[How to force Share Intent to open a specific app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app)

[Android Intent for Twitter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String url = "http://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=YOURURL&text=YOURTEXT";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Basically it should open the twitter app, if twitter is unavailable it will go to the browser instead

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have tried this already. I think the issue lies in 'setClassName' more specifically when setting the class name, "com.twitter.android.PostActivity" is outdated I think. Do you know of a way to find the current one the Twitter app is using?

Comment: Aye, that way does work, however, later down the line I want to add images as well. From what I've read you can't include images this way. I appreciate your help