# Specify which app respond to intent startActivity call

Tags: android, phone-call, android-phone-call

I am developing a simple android application for my job

There is a button that when clicked fires an ACTION_CALL intent to a series of phone numbers. the problem is, my phone is opening skype to try and make the call and I want it to use the built in native phone app. this is the code that runs the intent call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:989653523"));
                startActivity(intent);
```

I realize that "tel:" protocol can work for both Skype and the native Phone app but how can I make it so the app can always open it using the native phone app?

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app) post, look through the answers, the answer by Derzu looks interesting.

Comment: It could mean that Skype is set as your default calling app, have you tried to set back the native phone app to be the default

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to make an explicit intent call.

```
Intent i=new Intent (this,theActivityYouWantToStart.class);
```

Comment: The question is talking about implicit intents and not explicit.

Comment: @LieForBananas. Read carefully his post. If he uses implicit intent any app that can make call will show up as an option. He needs to make an explicit intent to call a specific app.

Comment: Nowhere in his question he mentioned implicit. Did I get this wrong?

Comment: Exactly but how will he know the Activity name of this specific app?

Comment: If he wants a specific app it has to be done using a package name and so on, as mentioned in the answers that I linked under the question.