# Choosing default intent in android share app

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi guys I'm developing an app where in i need to choose an app to share my status. 
I'm using something like this

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Myintent, "Share..."));
```

But the above line opens a window asking user to select the app to share with.

I want that option to be automated.. precisely I'm looking to update status on google plus.. 
So I need to start activity which chooses google plus to share...

Im guessing I need the activity name but com.google.android.app.plus opens google plus app but not the page that shares  the status... Im looking to prepopulate the status string so that user just have to press send

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the [Google plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/)?  You could send the data via http requests so that you would be able to stay in-app throughout the whole process.  I think this kind of solution could be a much smoother experience for the user so they wouldn't have to move in and out of your app in order to accomplish posting to google plus.

Comment: Google plus API app as per what Ive read is only to read data... but not write comments... So...

Comment: And also I dont mind goin out of my app as I have a very small time line to finish the app and I cant start learning the API now and design a gui appropiately

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229654/857583

In this case, call `initShareItent("plus");`

But you'll have to change the mime type to plain/text or something else.

It is starting the Google+ app, but the recipient or mail address is not filled in unfortunately.

So, `EXTRA_TEXT` is filled in but `EXTRA_MAIl` is not.