# Android share intent for facebook- share text AND link

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

I am trying to use the Android share intent to post something on facebook. It looks like this:

```
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Free education for all! http://linkd.in/xU8mCc");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

So my post has both - some text and a link. But when the message is posted on facebook, it only has the link, no message. I tried various extras but nothing works.

Anyone faced this issue and solved it? I have facebook app version 1.8.1

Edit: I tried removing the link, and the facebook app does not take my message (shows a blank message to be posted), but not the other way round. So looks like the app is totally ignoring any plain text messages. I am spooked! Is this a major bug in the fb app that text messages can not be posted at all (with share intent)?

Comment: hello GreenBee i have same problem but this link is not open now [here is my Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001859/unable-to-share-text-with-a-link-through-android-share-intent) please help me how to solve this problem

Comment: This is my solution which is working fine just for sharing URL, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29529335/513413

Answer (score 12):

I just built this code and it's working for me:

```
private void shareAppLinkViaFacebook(String urlToShare) {
    try {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        intent1.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.activity.composer.ImplicitShareIntentHandler");
        intent1.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
        intent1.setType("text/plain");
        intent1.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", urlToShare);
        startActivity(intent1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If we failed (not native FB app installed), try share through SEND
        String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + urlToShare;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems try{} function does not work although I have Facebook app installed on my device but catch works fine.

Comment: Where is the message here?

Comment: intent1.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");  use this instead of          intent1.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.activity.composer.ImplicitShareIntentHandler");

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to use the regular Android Sharing Intents, then unfortunately the Facebook sharing intent can only take a single URL (make sure it has http://) and no additional text message. It is a strange limitation that doesn't really make sense.

You have to use the actual official separate Facebook Android SDK in your project to get the full sharing functionality. Which is extra work.

I ran in to similar issues. In the end, what I did was branch the intent. If they choose to share (in the regular android share intent) via Facebook, create a new share intent that only has the URL and push that to facebook. All other share options (twitter, message, email) would work like normal.

my question and solution are here:

[Branching the Android Share Intent extras depending on which method they choose to share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450867/branching-the-android-share-intent-extras-depending-on-which-method-they-choose)

```
  String shareBody = "app string text " + act_txt + " more text! Get the app at http://www.appurl.com";

PackageManager pm = view.getContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, 0);
for(final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
     Log.i(TAG, "app.actinfo.name: " + app.activityInfo.name);
    //if((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
          if("com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {


        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.appurl.com");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share idea"));
        break;
    } else {
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "app name");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share"));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But why do you always `break` in a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2):

In Lollipop (21), you can use `Intent.EXTRA_REPLACEMENT_EXTRAS` to override the intent for specific apps.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_REPLACEMENT_EXTRAS

```
private void doShareLink(String text, String link) {
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
  Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_via));

  // for 21+, we can use EXTRA_REPLACEMENT_EXTRAS to support the specific case of Facebook
  // (only supports a link)
  // >=21: facebook=link, other=text+link
  // <=20: all=link
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text + " " + link);
    Bundle facebookBundle = new Bundle();
    facebookBundle.putString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);
    Bundle replacement = new Bundle();
    replacement.putBundle("com.facebook.katana", facebookBundle);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACEMENT_EXTRAS, replacement);
  } else {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);
  }

  chooserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(chooserIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app I have integrated Facebook SDK to enable users  share the quote [ pre filled text ] on their wall. Using FB SDK, it is possible to do this. It works in my app and I have more than 5K users using the same.

Apparently this is not against the policy of FB as I have not had any warning or an issue where this did not work.

The code snippets for the same can be found here,

[Do any widely used Android apps have Facebook sharing with pre-populated text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462006/do-any-widely-used-android-apps-have-facebook-sharing-with-pre-populated-text-fi/30650133#30650133)

Answer (score 0):

**USe this code for share image ,video,link and text on facebook working perfectally**

```
 public class Shareonwall extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    JSONObject response, profile_pic_data, profile_pic_url;
    TextView user_name, user_email;
    ImageView user_picture;
    NavigationView navigation_view;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;

    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private Uri fileUri;
    //   public static TextView output;

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 110;

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 222;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA_VIDEO = 333;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        facebookSDKInitialize();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button imageShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageShare);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home Page");

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String jsondata = intent.getStringExtra("jsondata");

        setNavigationHeader();    // call setNavigationHeader Method.
        setUserProfile(jsondata);  // call setUserProfile Method.


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);  // intialize facebook shareDialog.

        navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                            .setContentTitle("How to integrate Facebook from your app")
                            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.devglan.com/image/dashboard.jpg"))
                            .setContentDescription(
                                    "simple Fb Image share integration")
                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.devglan.com/image/dashboard.jpg"))
                            .build();

                    shareDialog.show(linkContent);  // Show facebook ShareDialog
                }
            }
        });

        imageShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

    }

    // this method is for create a dialog box to choose options to select Image to share on facebook.
    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library","Record Video",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Shareonwall.this);
        builder.setTitle("Select profile Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {



                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Shareonwall.this,
                                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Shareonwall.this,
                                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {



                            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);


                        } else {

                            if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Shareonwall.this,
                                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Shareonwall.this,
                                    android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

                            } else {


                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Shareonwall.this,
                                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);


                            }

                        }
                    } else {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);;
                    }

                }     else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {



                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Shareonwall.this,
                                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(
                                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                                    SELECT_FILE);
                        } else {

                            if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Shareonwall.this,
                                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {


                            } else {


                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Shareonwall.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                                SELECT_FILE);
                    }


                } if (items[item].equals("Record Video")) {


                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Shareonwall.this,
                                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                            Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                            if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                            }
                        } else {

                            if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Shareonwall.this,
                                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {


                            } else {


                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Shareonwall.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA_VIDEO);


                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    }


                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE){

                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);


            }

            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA){

                onCaptureImageResult(data);

            }
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //   Uri videoUri = data.getData();
                //   mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
                //  recordVideo(videoUri);
                String selectedVideoFilePath = GetFilePathFromDevice.getPath(this, data.getData());
                final byte[] datas;
                try {
                    datas = readBytes(selectedVideoFilePath,data.getData());
                    PostVideo(datas, selectedVideoFilePath);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }
    public byte[] readBytes(String dataPath,Uri uri) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        ShareDialogVideo(uri);
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
    public void PostVideo(byte[] VideoBytes, String filePath) {
        String url;
        url = "/me/videos";

        AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (token != null) {
            Bundle param = new Bundle();
            param.putByteArray("video." + getFileExt(filePath), VideoBytes);
            param.putString("description", "sample video");
            new GraphRequest(token,url, param, HttpMethod.POST, new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.e("New Post", "Res =" + response.toString());
                    //  dialog.dismiss();

                    if (response != null && response.getJSONObject() != null && response.getJSONObject().has("id")) {
                        Log.e("New Post", "Success");
                        Toast.makeText(Shareonwall.this, "Video posted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Shareonwall.this, "Error in posting Video.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                    finish();
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
    }
    public static String getFileExt(String fileName) {
        return fileName.substring((fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1), fileName.length());
    }

    /**** this method used for select image From Gallery  *****/


    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
                null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

        Bitmap thumbnail;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
        int scale = 1;
        while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;
        options.inSampleSize = scale;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

        ShareDialog(thumbnail);
    }

    /***  this method used for take profile photo *******/

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ShareDialog(thumbnail);
    }



    // This method is used to share Image on facebook timeline.
    public void ShareDialog(Bitmap imagePath){

        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(imagePath)
                .setCaption("Testing")
                .build();
        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(content);

    }
    public void ShareDialogVideo(Uri imagePath){

        ShareVideo  shareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
                .setLocalUrl(imagePath)
                .build();
        ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                .setVideo(shareVideo)
                .build();
        shareDialog.show(content);

    }


    // Initialize the facebook sdk and then callback manager will handle the login responses.

    protected void facebookSDKInitialize() {

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    /*
        Set Navigation header by using Layout Inflater.
     */

    public void setNavigationHeader(){

        navigation_view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_home, null);
        navigation_view.addHeaderView(header);

        user_name = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.username);
        user_picture = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        user_email = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.email);
    }

    /*
       Set User Profile Information in Navigation Bar.
     */

    public  void  setUserProfile(String jsondata){

        try {
            response = new JSONObject(jsondata);
            user_email.setText(response.get("email").toString());
            user_name.setText(response.get("name").toString());
            profile_pic_data = new JSONObject(response.get("picture").toString());
            profile_pic_url = new JSONObject(profile_pic_data.getString("data"));

            Picasso.with(this).load(profile_pic_url.getString("url"))
                    .into(user_picture);

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            SELECT_FILE);

                } else {


                }
                return;
            }

            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

                } else {


                }
                return;
            }
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA_VIDEO :{

                Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

                }



            }



            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }


}
```