# Unable to share text with a link through Android Share Intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

now i want to share text with a link below is my code

```
String myText = "Hey!\nThis is a my Text!";

Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
String extraText = "www.mylink.com\n\n" + myText ;
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extraText);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share with Friends"));
```

so it work work fine with gmail, twitter etc. but it is not working on facebook

**on facebook it share only link but there are not shown my text**

i want to this type sharing

```
www.mylink.com

here is my text
```

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android and Facebook share intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

Comment: This is my solution which is working fine just for sharing URL on Facebook, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29529335/513413

Comment: [he problem you have here is probably that Facebook doesn't look at the extra information provided in the Intent. Because it works for Gmail and Twitter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618514/share-text-via-intent-on-facebook-without-using-facebook-sdk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have here is probably that Facebook doesn't look at the extra information provided in the Intent. Because it works for Gmail and Twitter.

Have a look at [Android and Facebook share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent) by the way..

Answer (score 1):

you cant share link with text on FB using Share Intent,
You must try to do this the FB graph API for wall post .