# Using clickable links in intent.putextra

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I'm using `intent.putextra()` to share the intent to `Facebook` and `Twitter`. But I have a simple question: is it possible to insert a clickable link into the string used in `putextra()`?

 Let's make an example. This code:

```
Intent shareintent = new Intent();
shareintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Whatever");
shareintent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(shareintent);
```

will share "Whatever" to the selected service. I just want to put something like the "a href" tag used in `HTML` so that I can set a link that redirects the user to a specific page...
Any idea?
UPDATE: appearantly when the choosen sharing method starts it doesn't have the content I put into putextra...
 For example: if I choose Facebook the intent opens a blank post page instead of posting "Whatever"... o.O

Comment: Maybe you are searching for [a link text view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877595/i-want-text-view-as-a-clickable-link)?

Comment: hmmm nope. I want the text to be clickable when already shared.
For example: when I share "whatever" on FB I want other FB users to be able to click on it and be redirected to a page...

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to insert a clickable link into the string used in
>   putextra()?

The way you code, makes the link clickable or not. You can send the link-text to next activity using intent as shown in your example. And in next activity you can make that link clikable and navigate to desired page.

**EDIT:**

> well I can't make the link clickable in the next activity because the
>   next activity is an other app

In that case you need to put a URL in the EXTRA_TEXT field. But if you put only simple text then it won't be clickable in `Facebook`.  However it will work in `Twitter`.

Check following links.

1. [Android-and-facebook-share-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)
2. [Unable to share text with link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001859/unable-to-share-text-with-a-link-through-android-share-intent)

Comment: well I can't make the link clickable in the next activity because the next activity is an other app (used to share the content) xD

Comment: I have updated my answer with few useful links. Hope it helps you.