# Posting a Score in Facebook from Android App

Tags: android

I am using following code. When I choose twitter app It shows "My score is with snake game is 2000" text in tweet dialog but it doesn't show text in Facebook post dialog

```
Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"My score is with snake game is 2000");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The title");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but the fb android app doesn't implement (correctly) the apis. The only solution i found is use the fb android sdk (com.facebook.android):

```
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("caption", "The title");
    parameters.putString("description", "My score is with snake game is 2000");
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", parameters, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't allow you to set the message for the user. This is a known issue and has been asked about many times before. Facebook has started moving towards letting you prefill a message (at least in the iOS 6+ native FB share). Perhaps this will be opened up in the future...

See [Android share intent for facebook- share text AND link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771333/android-share-intent-for-facebook-share-text-and-link)