# Android - share the app link to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have a button "Share on Facebook".

```
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```

By clicking it, how I can share app's Play Market link to Facebook if I have Facebook SDK attached?

Comment: Check the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771333/android-share-intent-for-facebook-share-text-and-link

Comment: This only loads my FB page, but no post is added on my wall.

Comment: It worked. I just used incorrect link.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void sendShareFacebook(String strShareMessage) 
{
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mIntent.setType("text/plain");
        mIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strShareMessage);
        try {
            mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Utility.toastShort(mContext, "Facebook not installed");
        }
    }
```