# How to customize share intent in Android (which is possible)

Tags: android

All the while, I thought it is not possible to customize share intent in Android : [How to customize share intent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827407/how-to-customize-share-intent-in-android)

But, this nicely done app (Timely) had changed my view.

[image]

I was wondering, how do they make

- Customized title
- Customized body message
- `More` button
- One tap on icon will launch the right app, no longer have `Always` and `Just once` button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a custom dialog or dialog-themed activity, populated from `PackageManager` via `queryIntentActivities()`, most likely.