# add Tumblr tags in Share Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, tumblr

I'd like to add default tags in Tumblr through the Share Intent. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827407/how-to-customize-share-intent-in-android) post.
I can only out EXTRA_TEXT, EXTRA_SUBJECT, EXTRA_STREAM, but no tags there.

Comment: There is nothing standard in Android for tags. You would need to ask the Tumblr folk if they have their own custom extras for that.

Comment: but that would mean that I should use their API, instead of Android Intent functions?