# How to send Email with attachment using only email apps?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

**There are two requirements:**

- Email with attachment
- In the `Intent` chooser, there should be only Email apps.

**What I have known/done:**

- `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` with `intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"))` can make sure that there are only Email apps in `Intent` chooser but it will not bring attachment(For some apps like Gmail it will, but there are also many apps that will ignore attachment).
- `Intent.ACTION_SEND` can send Email with attachment. However, in `Intent` chooser, there will be apps that are actually not Email apps but can response to `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. Using `intent.setType("message/rfc822")` can reduce number of those apps but not all.
- References this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550043/3952691 and nearly succeed in my goals. My code is as below:

  ```
  private static void sendFeedbackWithAttachment(Context context, String subject) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
      intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));

      PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
      List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
      if (resolveInfos.isEmpty()) {
          Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_activity_not_found),
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else {
          // ACTION_SEND may be replied by some apps that are not email apps. However,
          // ACTION_SENDTO doesn't allow us to choose attachment. As a result, we use
          // an ACTION_SENDTO intent with email data to filter email apps and then send
          // email with attachment by ACTION_SEND.
          List<LabeledIntent> intents = new ArrayList<>();
          Uri uri = getLatestLogUri();
          for (ResolveInfo info : resolveInfos) {
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              i.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
              i.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
              i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { Def.Meta.FEEDBACK_EMAIL });
              i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
              i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
              intents.add(new LabeledIntent(i, info.activityInfo.packageName,
                      info.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()), info.icon));
          }
          Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intents.remove(0),
                  context.getString(R.string.send_feedback_to_developer));
          chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                  intents.toArray(new LabeledIntent[intents.size()]));
          context.startActivity(chooser);
      }
  }
  ```

  However, on some devices(For example, Xiaomi 2S with MIUI V5, I don't know if this can be influenced by a third-party rom), the result is an empty `Intent` chooser. And it seems that above Android 6.0, `Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` has some bugs([Custom intent-chooser - why on Android 6 does it show empty cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842612/custom-intent-chooser-why-on-android-6-does-it-show-empty-cells), and another one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202693).

As a result, I don't know how to achieve my goals. Please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: "Intent.ACTION_SENDTO with intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")) can make sure that there are only Email apps in Intent chooser" -- no, it does not. It puts in the chooser any app that elects to support that `Intent` structure. Anyone can write such an app, and it may not be an "Email app". There is no universal declaration of what "Email apps" are.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I know it. But I'm talking about common case. We can say, an app which has a `IntentFilter` for `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and data scheme as "mailto", if it is a formal app, it should have the ability to handle Email events thus we can see it as an "Email app".

Comment: @ywwynm Use .setType("message/rfc822") or the chooser will show you all of the (many) applications that support the send intent.

Comment: @Stanojkovic Could you please see my question description carefully? In "What I have known/done" section, I said that I have tried to use "message/rfc822" but it didn't meet my demand.

Comment: @ywwynm  This is how I manage sending mails:
`String mailTo = "email@gmail.com";`
`Intent email_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", mailTo, null));`

Comment: @ywwynm maybe youll find something usefull here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974987/how-to-send-an-email-with-a-file-attachment-in-android, this guy had putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

Comment: @Stanojkovic I did say "`Intent.ACTION_SEND` can send Email with attachment" in "what I have known/done" section, right? So I know how to attach file using `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. I  know that very very very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to Send a mail

```
String filename="filename.vcf"; 
File filelocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filelocation); 
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// set the type to 'email'
emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
String to[] = {"asd@gmail.com"};
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
// the attachment
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
// the mail subject
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
```

Comment: What about **message/rfc822**, does that set the email type?

Answer (score -2):

There are two ways to do this

**OPTION 1**

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
            android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

     
     //Option 1
    Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + "blah blah subject"
            + "&body=" + "blah blah body" + "&to=" + "sendme@me.com");
    emailIntent.setData(data);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, ""));
```

Result

[image]

**OPTION 2**

It works perfactly except it wont filter out FTP

```
    //Option 2
  emailIntent = new Intent(
            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    final String[] toRecipients = new String[] { "sendme@me.com", "", };
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, toRecipients);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "blah blah subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            Html.fromHtml("blah blah body"));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, ""));
```

Result

[image]

Both ways have minor flaws I show you both ways it is now upto you to pick one.