# why Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS not working in android 10

Tags: android

I am trying to share some text, In Android 10 always show max 3 apps [in my mobile have WhatsApp but this not displaying here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOmtW.jpg)

This code is properly working in below 10 devices but could not find the reason why in android 10 is filtering out.

```
fun onShareClick() {
        val intentShareList = ArrayList<Intent>()
        val shareIntent = Intent()
        shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        shareIntent.type = "text/plain"
        val resolveInfoList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0)
        for (resInfo in resolveInfoList) {
            val packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.packageName
            val name = resInfo.activityInfo.name
            if (packageName.contains("com.facebook") ||
                packageName.contains("com.twitter.android") ||
                packageName.contains("com.google.android.gm") ||
                packageName.contains("com.android.mms") ||
                packageName.contains("com.whatsapp")
            ) {
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.component = ComponentName(packageName, name)
                intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                intent.type = "text/plain"
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject")
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your Content")
                intentShareList.add(intent)
            }
        }
        if (intentShareList.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No apps to share !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentShareList.removeAt(0), "Share via")
            chooserIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                intentShareList.toTypedArray()
            )
            startActivity(chooserIntent)
        }
    }
```

In the `intentShareList` contains WhatsApp info but not displaying

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57846229)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. It seems the problem is in some Android 10 devices (like Samsung), not all. I solved using `Intent.EXTRA_EXCLUDE_COMPONENTS` instead of `Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`, and creating an array of `ComponentName` to be excluded. Refactoring your code:

```
fun onShareClick() {
    val excludedComponents = ArrayList<ComponentName>()
    val shareIntent = Intent()
    shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    shareIntent.type = "text/plain"
    val resolveInfoList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0)
    for (resInfo in resolveInfoList) {
        val packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.packageName
        val name = resInfo.activityInfo.name
        if (!(packageName.contains("com.facebook") ||
            packageName.contains("com.twitter.android") ||
            packageName.contains("com.google.android.gm") ||
            packageName.contains("com.android.mms") ||
            packageName.contains("com.whatsapp"))
        ) {
            excludedComponents.add(ComponentName(packageName, name))
        }
    }
    if (excludedComponents.size()==resolveInfoList.size()) {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No apps to share !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent , "Share via")
        chooserIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_EXCLUDE_COMPONENTS,
            excludedComponents.toTypedArray()
        )
        startActivity(chooserIntent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create your chooser using the initial intent and add your intentShareList as extra, like this:

```
val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via")
        chooserIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
            intentShareList.toTypedArray()
        )
        startActivity(chooserIntent)
```

I think it will bring what you want. Let me know if it helps :)

EDIT: Even if you put on your shareIntent a inicial EXTRA_INTENT and  a type, Android Q will ignore what you added on EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, so it wont help

I was reading about this on that issue and I think it wont be fixed, take a look = https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134367295

Also, there some information on documentation that says using EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS to personalized data is not recomended, and its was made to helping share links and it can reduce the apps who will appear, take a look = https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

Well, Im very sad about that, Idk what do to also, maybe a unique text... :(

Answer (score 2):

My answer may not answer OP's question but if you want to exclude a specified package, you can refer to it. This solution also works on pre-Android 11 OS.

For me, EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS doesn't work on Android 11. So I handled 2 flows for 2 cases (Android 11 or later and pre-Android).

The below code will exclude Facebook out of share options.

**1. Add the Facebook package to Android Manifest** for expanding package visibility on Android 11. You can [check out](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility#all-apps)

```
<manifest ...>
...

    <queries>
        ...
        <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
    </queries>
...
</manifest>
```

**2. Create an intent chooser:**

```
   private fun getShareChooserWithoutFacebook(
        context: Context,
        template: Intent
    ): Intent {

        // get available share intents
        val targets: MutableList<Intent> = mutableListOf()
        val candidates: List<ResolveInfo> =
            context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(template, 0)
        val excludedComponents = ArrayList<ComponentName>()

        // remove facebook which has a broken share intent
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            for (candidate in candidates) {
                val packageName = candidate.activityInfo.packageName
                if (!packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana")) {
                    val target = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    target.type = "text/plain"
                    target.putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        template.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT)
                    )
                    target.putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        template.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
                    )
                    target.setPackage(packageName)
                    targets.add(target)
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (candidate in candidates) {
                val packageName = candidate.activityInfo.packageName
                val name = candidate.activityInfo.name
                if ((packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana"))) {
                    excludedComponents.add(ComponentName(packageName, name))
                }
            }
        }

        var chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(template, context.getString(R.string.settings_send_via))

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            chooserIntent =
                Intent.createChooser(targets.removeAt(0), context.getString(R.string.settings_send_via))
            chooserIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                targets.toTypedArray()
            )
        } else {
            chooserIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_EXCLUDE_COMPONENTS,
                excludedComponents.toTypedArray()
            )
        }

        return chooserIntent

    }
```

**3. Open the intent chooser**

```
   fun openShareChooser(context: Context, title: String?, content: String?) {
        val template = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        template.type = "text/plain"
        template.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title)
        template.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content)
        context.startActivity(
            getShareChooserWithoutFacebook(context, template)
        )
    }
```