# Open facebook link in chooser with browsers

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

Сan we open the facebook link so that the menu selection of applications for viewing the content was still and facebook browsers? The standard startup

```
fun openLink(link: String) {
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        data = Uri.parse(link)

        context.startActivity( this)
    }
 }
```

opens only browsers, and some browsers, such as chrome and edge, run another one, where then appears facebook (if it is installed), the only thing I was able to find was to open the links directly to facebook, if it is installed, without the possibility of choosing an application to open the link

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            try {
                val applicationInfo: ApplicationInfo = 
                       packageManager.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0)
                if (applicationInfo.enabled) {
                    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/24547437/1048340
                    data = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://facebook.com/")
                }
            } catch (ignored: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
                data = Uri.parse("https://facebook.com/")
            }

            startActivity(this)
        }
```

1. [what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PijhE.png)
2. [what i want and what chorme send after open facebook link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDq6L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you familiar with `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`? create two separate `Intent`s (if fb app present and enabled) and join them

```
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Open in...");
if (fbIntent != null) {
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { fbIntent });
}
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

some more info in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021021/how-to-make-an-intent-with-multiple-actions) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786777/why-intent-extra-initial-intents-not-working-in-android-10)