# How to add a custom option(Dowload Image) with other share options in android

Tags: android, android-intent-chooser

Is it possible to add a custom option(For eg. Download Image) with other share option(shown in attached image) in intent chooser?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/building-content-sharing.html

Comment: @akash93 thanks for sharing link but this did not help me. Please suggest something else.

Comment: Have you gone through the link? It contains ( more specifically [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) ) exactly what you need

Comment: @akash93 This does not help. We need to have a Download option in Intent chooser

Comment: You haven't gone through the link then.. When you register your application using an `intent-filter` and `image` mime-type the callback your app receives contains the image Uri which can be used to access the file. This is **clearly explained** in the documentation link I posted earlier..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I did not get useful answers. I did a workaround to solve this.

Here is the code to add a custom 'Save to Gallery" option(shown in attached image)

```
Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(aContext, DownloadActivity.class);
downloadIntent.putExtra("url", url);
intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(downloadIntent, "com.don.offers", "Save To Gallery", R.drawable.ic_save_to_gallery));

// convert intentList to array
LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray(new LabeledIntent[intentList.size()]);
openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
```

Here DownloadActivity is transparent activity that has the code to download image.

```
public class DownloadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String imageUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);

        imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        saveToGallery();
        finish();
    }


    public void saveToGallery() {
        try {
            String DIR_NAME = "Don Downloaded Images";
            String filename = "DON_IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
            //String downloadUrlOfImage = "http://fun.localdon.com/DonUGCImg/DON_memes14908366211071492831321991.png";
            String downloadUrlOfImage = imageUrl;
            File direct =
                    new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String.valueOf(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES))
                            .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_NAME + "/");


            if (!direct.exists()) {
                direct.mkdir();
                Log.e("saveToGallery", "dir created for first time");
            }

            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) DownloadActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(downloadUrlOfImage);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                    .setTitle(filename)
                    .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
                    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(String.valueOf(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                            File.separator + DIR_NAME + File.separator + filename);

            dm.enqueue(request);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                final Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                final Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(direct);
                scanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                DownloadActivity.this.sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
            } else {
                final Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
                DownloadActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If anyone has better approach please share.Thanks

Comment: Where did you get intentList?

Comment: @Adnan I did not post whole code, if you need it I will do. intentList is array list to which filtered packages to show in intent chooser added.

Comment: Sapna: Alright Kindly post the entire code here or share it on my email shoutadnan@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

Refer this answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27187951/3835367)

Sample Code:
[Github Project](https://github.com/xinanadu/CustomShare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/info/zhegui/share/MainActivity.java)

Comment: @SapnaSharma I didn't try personally. But what is the issue you're facing?